# mysql select a geometry class from a geometry collection

Tags: mysql, geometry, spatial, spatial-query, wkt

I am setting up a Geometry Collection in a MySql database. I have added various geometry classes thus:

> SET @g ='GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POINT(1 1),LINESTRING(0 1,2 3,4 5), POINT(6 6))';
>   INSERT INTO myTable (geoCollectionField) VALUES (GeomFromText(@g));

The `geoCollectionField` responds as expected in the WKT formay:

> GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POINT(1 1),LINESTRING(0 1,2 3,4 5),POINT(6 6))

I can fetch the data from this Geometry Collection in several ways.

> SELECT geoCollectionField FROM myTable;

gives the complete GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POINT(1 1),LINESTRING...

> SELECT AsText(GeometryN(geoCollectionField, 1)) FROM myTable;

gives the indexed geometry class POINT(1 1).

I have not been able to write a SELECT that fetches only one class type, for example the POINT classes to end up with POINT((1 1),(6 6)).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following steps:

1. Get the **number of geometries** in your `GeometryCollection` using `STNumGeometries` ([STNumGeometries Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933910.aspx))
2. Use a loop to iterate over all your geometries in your `GeometryCollection`.
3. Get the **geometry at** a specific **index** using `STGeometryN` ([STGeometryN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933831.aspx))
4. For each geometry get the **geometry type** using `STGeometryType` ([STGeometryType Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933825.aspx))
5. Check if the geometry type matches your desired type. If you have a match you might want to add it to a resulting `GeometryCollection`.

Following these steps would result in

```
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POINT(1 1), POINT(6 6))
```

You could also use other collections depending on your desired geometry type (`MultiPoint`, `MultiLineString`, `MultiPolygon`)

A Multipoint result could look like this:

```
MULTIPOINT((1 1), (6 6))
```